# How do I change the default document column margins in Pages?

Tags: pages

In Pages 8.1 on MacOS Mojave, I can't seem to change the default dimensions of the default column for the document body. I started a new document and chose Resume > Business Resume. I switched to the document inspector and zeroed out all of the margins as shown here:

[image]

As you can see, it has no effect on the left or top sizes as shown by the gray layout outline. I tried to uncheck document body, hoping it would reset the column, but it made no difference.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried a different template other than a Business resume?

Comment: Yes, but I want to know why the margins can't be changed.

Comment: I don't know why changing the document margins as you described doesn't work. it works fine for me but I'm running High Sierra.  Maybe it has something to do with Mojave.

Comment: I can change the margins, but I can't eliminate them entirely.  Do you have a screen shot showing the view layout?

Comment: The gray lines you see in the image is the margin boundaries.  When you look at the margin settings on the left, they are all zero.

Comment: Same issue here, unresolved for years. I guess you've never found a way to move these margins on those kinds of templates? I ended up creating a new empty doc, and copying it all on it, [problem solved](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393229/53900)

Comment: I guess it's a bug.