# Column width and document margins don't add up

Tags: pages

I am sure this question has been asked many times, I just couldn't find an answer on the web.

I am writing a letter (I started with one of the Pages templates).
Now I'd like to increase the width of the body of the text.

So I set the right Document Margin to 0; that increased the width a little, but I get nowhere near the edge of the paper.

I've got a paper size of A4, which has width 21 cm.
Looking at Format / Layout / Columns, I see that the column has a width = 14.5 cm.
Left document margin = 2.5 cm.
But 2.5 + 14.5 = 17 cm, not 21 cm!

Where is the rest of the width?
Why can't I increase the body text width further?

All hints and insights will be highly appreciated!
Best regards, Gabriel

PS:
Apple Pages version = 10.0 (6748), macOS Catalina (10.15)

Comment: Maybe I should add that I need to print on A4, and there is no "A4 Borderless" paper size in the pulldown.
Also, the problem seems to have to do with the ruler: even though the right margin is set to 0, I can't move the right ruler (blue triangle pointing down) to the right.

Comment: I think we could help you better if you include a screenshot of your Pages document with both the Ruler at the top and the Document sidebar on the right enabled (showing the Paper Size and the Document Margins). To get a screenshot of your document, press Command + Shift + 4 (all three at the same time) while in the document, and then Space and then click on your mouse (or trackpad).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up copying the whole body of the document into an empty, new document with a blank template. There, I could adjust the rulers and margins. The problem was, I think, the Informal Letter template, with which I had started. According to some other posts, that seems to have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

At the very top of an open document click on the 2 Document tabs on the right. This brings op options to set hard page boundaries. The first Documents tab I'm referring to is the one next to the Format tab and the next is below that. See image below.

[image]

If that doesn't work add the paper size US Letter borderless available via pulldown.